# Github cannot be established

Tags: windows-7, git

Hi I am trying to build Camunda Web App using Grunt. But it reports that Github server connection cannot established. How to fix it?

Windows 7, Git & Maven & NodeJS all are set up in environment variable "path".

```
C:\Workspace\CamundaSourceCode\camunda-bpm-webapp>grunt setup
Will start the platform with command
mvn clean install jetty:run -DskipTests -Pdevelop,livereload
Tests are skipped

Running "parallel:clone" (parallel) task
Cloning into 'camunda-bpm-sdk-js'...
Cloning into 'camunda-commons-ui'...
Cloning into 'camunda-admin-ui'...
Cloning into 'camunda-cockpit-ui'...
Cloning into 'camunda-tasklist-ui'...
Cloning into 'camunda-cockpit-plugin-base'...
The authenticity of host 'github.com (192.30.252.130)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is 16:27:ac:a5:76:28:2d:36:63:1b:56:4d:eb:df:a6:48.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? The authenticity of host 'github.com (192.30.252.130)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is 16:27:ac:a5:76:28:2d:36:63:1b:56:4d:eb:df:a6:48.The authenticity of host 'github.com (192.30.252.130)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is 16:27:ac:a5:76:28:2d:36:63:1b:56:4d:eb:df:a6:48.

Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? The authenticity of host 'github.com (192.30.252.130)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is 16:27:ac:a5:76:28:2d:36:63:1b:56:4d:eb:df:a6:48.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? The authenticity of host 'github.com (192.30.252.130)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is 16:27:ac:a5:76:28:2d:36:63:1b:56:4d:eb:df:a6:48.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? The authenticity of host 'github.com (192.30.252.130)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is 16:27:ac:a5:76:28:2d:36:63:1b:56:4d:eb:df:a6:48.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Please type 'yes' or 'no': yes
Please type 'yes' or 'no': yes
Please type 'yes' or 'no':
Host key verification failed.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

    >>
Warning: Task "parallel:clone" failed. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.

C:\Workspace\CamundaSourceCode\camunda-bpm-webapp>
```

Comment: Are you the one typing in `yes` there or is it automated?

Comment: I did. I also tried aquavitae's solution in this link but it didn't work. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20028556/openshift-plone-quickstart-permission-denied